# MySQL "INSERT" doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a PM system on my website however the sending does not work...

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$date = date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
$id = rand(0000,9999);

include('sql_connect.php');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pm (`from`, `to`, `content`, `date`, `id`) VALUES ('".$from."', '".$to."', '".$content."', '".$date."', '".$id."')");
mysql_close($con);
header('Location: members.php?sent');
?>
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work?

EDIT: I added backtits but the result is this:

```
NULL 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quebecen/public_html/new/do_pm.php:10) in /home/quebecen/public_html/new/do_pm.php on line 15
```

EDIT 2: I added $result before que mysql_query() (I forgot it) and now I have this code:

```
<?php
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$date = date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
$id = rand(0000,9999);

include('sql_connect.php');
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pm (`from`, `to`, `content`, `date`, `id`) VALUES ('".$from."', '".$to."', '".$content."', '".$date."', '".$id."')", $con);

var_dump($result);

if(!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}

mysql_close($con);
header('Location: members.php?sent');
?>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the webserver error log that will help us?

Comment: This code is plenty of sql injection possibility

Comment: What does mysql_query return? You should check this out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Also use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php to get the error.

Comment: The query return this: NULL You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, content, date, id) VALUES ('test', '113589', 'kbnsrtnsrnrynynynswry', ' at line 1
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quebecen/public_html/new/do_pm.php:10) in /home/quebecen/public_html/new/do_pm.php on line 15

Comment: I think you should try again with your first code.Because I tried and It works pretty well for me.

Comment: What is the tool you are using? Dreamviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error your getting is because your outputting the buffer & then trying to add a header; (This can be a single space or a carriage return or the error message its self, but in your case its the var_dump) . Also You have sql injections vulnerabilities from not escaping 
the post variables, I do suggest you forget about the mysql_* family of functions and move to PDO prepared statements:

```
<?php
//Start a session to hold the status
session_start();
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourDB", 'dbUser', 'dbPass');

    /*** set the error reporting attribute ***/
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /*** some variables ***/
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $date = date("Y-n-j H:i:s");

    $id = rand(0000,9999); //? This is wrongly implemented if you want a uniqie id, you should be using the AUTO INCREMENT value

    /*** prepare the SQL statement ***/
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO pm (`from`, `to`, `content`, `date`, `id`)VALUES(:from, :to, :content, :date, :id)");

    /*** bind the paramaters ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':from', $from, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($from));
    $stmt->bindParam(':to', $to, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($to));
    $stmt->bindParam(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($content));
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($date));


    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute();
    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;

    //Set as sent, redirect to members cleanly and then check session var is true
    $_SESSION['sent']=true;
    header('Location: ./members.php');
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    //Something went wrong
    $_SESSION['sent']=false;
    //You should log this error, and not output any internal errors to the user, just advise them something went wrong.
    error_log("FATAL MSG ERROR:".$e->getMessage(), 3, "/home/quebecen/logs/my-errors.log");

    header('Location: ./members.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the query isn't dying.

```
$result = mysql_query("...");
var_dump($result); //If $result is false, then there was an error executing the query.

if(!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

You might also not be using the correct connection. You might need to add `$con` to `mysql_query`.

```
mysql_query("...", $con);
```

Comment: NULL You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, content, date, id) VALUES ('test', '113589', 'kbnsrtnsrnrynynynswry', ' at line 1
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quebecen/public_html/new/do_pm.php:10) in /home/quebecen/public_html/new/do_pm.php on line 15

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with `$date`. Can you echo it right before the query?

Answer (score 0):

1) the header already sent error is pretty obvious, don't echo anything before using header() so the code should be :

```
if(!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
    mysql_close($con);
} else {
    mysql_close($con);
    header('Location: members.php?sent');
}
```

2) try using `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quebecen/public_html/new/do_pm.php:10) in /home/quebecen/public_html/new/do_pm.php on line 15

If you are going to use header function, make sure that there is no html contents will be displayed before that function.

Better you can use ob_start(); function before redirecting or first line of your page.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occurred due to the web authoring tool you are using.

You try following.

1. Copy the file name to somewhere. And backup your file.
2. Delete your existing file
3. Create a new php file using notepad or notepad++ (just text editor). And rename it for previous file name.
4. Copy your code to your file using the text editor. Copy exactly `<?php` to `?>` with no whitespace.

**Make sure you have no whitespace before `<?php`.**